# how to detect the phone state when someone call picked up

Tags: java, android

Here is the details which is am facing when to detect the picked sate .

1. Reading Phone State :- The problem with this approach is while we have outgoing call there is no such ringing state. When the call is ringing it is offhook state and when the call is picked up there is no change in state and thus we can't identify whether call is picked up or not.
2. Using Notification listener. In some phone it worked but in some phone like redmi it didn't work as there is not same change in notification. Your app will be fail in testing.
3. Accessibility service:- To access event the app need special permission which can be granted to only system apps or in rooted phone so it can't work as this permission is not granted.
4. Maintaining Call Log:- The call logs are updated when the call is done so you wil not get details of ongoing calls.

Even broadcast receiver also not working.Can anyone help me out . Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: This is not possible on purpose due to security concerns.

Comment: _"Accessibility service:- To access event the app need special permission which can be granted to only system apps or in rooted phone"_. That's not really true. While this permission can't be requested with a normal permission request dialog - the user can grant your app this permission through the Android Settings app. Whether Google Play will allow an app that uses an `AccessibilityService` for non-accessibility related things is a different matter.